# iText - trim cell text's height to cell's height

Tags: java, itext

I want to trim height of cell to height of content using iText. If I put Paragraph in Cell:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(prepare(new Paragraph("asd", textCellFont)));
table.addCell(cell);
```

there is a top padding and I dont know why.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The PdfPCell class has the **setPaddingTop** method, try:

```
cell.setPaddingTop(0)
```

if the top padding remains, the only other cause can be the paragraph leading contained in the cell.